# How can I pass an Angular Array in my $scope to a function by reference instead of by value?

Tags: angularjs

In my form, I am passing a model off the scope to a behavior like this:

```
                   <a href="#"
                       ng-click="removeAnEditSelectionFromModelCollection(data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer, actionRecommendedByLer.lookUpDetailId, 'editActionRecommendedByLerSelect')"
                       class="functionalLinks text-danger">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        DELETE
                    </a>
```

The model is an Angular array:
$scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer

The receiving function looks like this:

```
$scope.removeAnEditSelectionFromModelCollection = function (modelCollection, lookUpDetailId, selectId) {
            console.log("In removeAnEditSelectionFromModelCollection");
            modelCollection
                = $.grep(modelCollection,
                    function (n, i) {
                        console.log("n.lookUpDetailId: " + n.lookUpDetailId + ", lookUpDetailId: " + lookUpDetailId);
                        return (n.lookUpDetailId !== lookUpDetailId);
                    }
                 )
            console.log("modelCollection.length: " + modelCollection.length);

            var element = $('#' + selectId + ' option[value = "' + lookUpDetailId + '"]');
            // console.log(element.text());
            element.removeAttr('disabled');
            element.css('background-color', '');
        }
```

It seems like it is passed by value.  Can I pass this by reference somehow so after the grep my table with the ng-repeat against the Angular Array will reflect the update?

Comment: No need to pass the scope variables in Angular

Comment: where is the `ng-repeat`? ng-repeat gets a separate scope for every template instance (every 'repeat'). maybe your problem is there...
why do you think it is passed by value?

Comment: pass by reference means what in angular?

Comment: What I really need to do is access an array dynamically like this:
$scope[modelCollectionName] =  myGrepFunction();

modelCollectionName could be "data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer", "data.editAction.actionType1.actionCharges" etc.

I am trying to write a generic behavior to remove a record from the array model.  Otherwise I'll have to write like a hundred of these.  I have my nongeneric verison working but I need to access these $scope Array vars dynamically.